# Evitar que la página se recargue al presionar F5 con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quiero evitar que la página recargue cuando alguien presiona `F5`, la primera vez que presiona funciona, pero si presiona nuevamente se recarga la página, esto el lo que tengo de código:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 116 && $('#recargar').html() == 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            confirm('Si recarga la página perdera todos los datos ingresados,<br> ¿Deseas recargar la página?"', function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    recargar = false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ¿y qué pasa si presiona Ctrl+R o hace click en el botón actualizar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te aconsejaria que no bloquees nada, lo mejor seria guardar tu información de manera local, y aunque el usuario refresque el navegador tus variables se mantendran a salvo.

Deberias usar ***localStorage o sessionStorage***

Puedes almacenar hasta 5 mb de información
**un poco de teoria:**

> LocalStorage: Guarda información que permanecerá almacenada por tiempo
>   indefinido; sin importar que el navegador se cierre.
>
> sessionStorage: Almacena los datos de una sesión y éstos se eliminan
>   cuando el navegador se cierra.

su manera de uso: vas guardando como en un array

```
localStorage.setItem("nombre", variable );
```

para recuperar el dato:

```
var cAux = localStorage.getItem("nombre");
```

> te dejo un ejemplo funcional, pruebalo localmente, en SOes no funciona
>   no se porque

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('#boton-guardar').click(function(){        
var nom = document.getElementById("capNombre").value;
var ap= document.getElementById("capApellido").value;
localStorage.setItem("Nombre", nom);
localStorage.setItem("Apellido", ap);
document.getElementById("capNombre").value = "";
document.getElementById("capApellido").value = "";
   });  
});

$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('#boton-cargar').click(function(){     
var nombre = localStorage.getItem("Nombre");
var apellido = localStorage.getItem("Apellido");
document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML = nombre;
document.getElementById("apellido").innerHTML = apellido;
   });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="capNombre">
<input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" id="capApellido">
<button id="boton-guardar">Guardar</button>
<button id="boton-cargar">Cargar elementos</button>
<div id="nombre">
<div id="apellido">
```

Comment: ¿Por que guardarlo local? Es decir, que te asegura que el usuario va a usar el mismo desktop, labtop,  browser o si lo esta usando en modo incógnito.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo lo mismo sucedera con el ejemplo que se plantea en la pregunta

Comment: ¿Que es lo que sucedería? No he entendido a que te refieres.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar que se recargue, cierre la pagina o navegue a otra, puede usar [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload).

> Existe [un bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587940) en `Chrome y Firefox 4+`, la cadena de texto no se muestra al usuario.

Ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('recargar').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.location.reload();
});
document.getElementById('desactivar').addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', askConfirmation);
});

function askConfirmation (evt) {
  var msg = 'Si recarga la página perdera todos los datos ingresados.\n¿Deseas recargar la página?';
  evt.returnValue = msg;
  return msg;
}
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', askConfirmation);
```

```html
<button id="recargar">Recargar</button>
<button id="desactivar">Des-activar confirmación</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

De ésta forma te debería de funcionar siempre. ya lo testee. Saludos

```js
function Verificar()
{
var tecla=window.event.keyCode;
if (tecla==116) {
 confirm('Si recarga la página perdera todos los datos ingresados,<br> ¿Deseas recargar la página?"', function (result) {
     if (result) {
           location.reload();
      } else {
           event.keyCode=0;
event.returnValue=false;
      }
}); 

}
}
```

```html
<body onKeyDown="javascript:Verificar()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Me funcionó esto:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
    // Cancelar el evento antes de la descarga (esto no evita el refresh completo)
    event.preventDefault();
    // Establecer el mensaje a mostrar al usuario
    event.returnValue = '¡Personaliza tu mensaje aquí!'; 
    // Retorna el mensaje para que se muestre al usuario
    return event.returnValue;
    });
```